# Alasql - Having columns with sub-columns

Tags: alasql

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfaPs.png

I am attempting to do nested columns similar to the image I have linked above, as I have multiple columns that are grouped to a single header but I'm not sure how to do this.

I was assuming I could do something like:

```
var options  = {
  columns:  [
    {
      title: Event,
      columns: [{columnid:'event_id', title: 'Event ID'},
                {columnid:'event_name', title: 'Event Name'},
                {columnid:'event_vendor_id', title: 'Vendor ID'},]
    }
  ]
}
```

This doesn't work though, and looking through the source code I'm not certain there is a way to accomplish what I'm attempting.

If anyone has any suggestions I would greatly appreciate it, thanks!